# Where did the line terminator go after this php snippet?

Tags: php, html

Here is my HTML code.

```
<?php
   // php code that adds a single div
?>

<script id = "conf">
```

There is clearly two return characters after the final

```
?>
```

However, the output is like this:

```
<div id='conf'></div>
<script id = "conf">
```

It seems a return character (line terminator ) was "sucked up".  It appears that the PHP snippet does this some how.

Why is this?

Is this expected behavior?

I just find it odd.  Obviously a return character could be added, but how is one subtracted?  Just find it odd.

**Clarification:**

I'm talking about under view source.  Not the actual HTML document.

Comment: There should be one empty line before `<div>`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> The closing tag for the block will include the immediately trailing newline if one is present.

As per [the PHP manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.basic-syntax.instruction-separation.php).

I agree it seems a bit strange. I ran into this behavior when trying to format and indent the resulting HTML. To force a newline, add a space at the end of the line and it will be rendered.

Comment: Googled for "php newline after closing tag".